# Using Channel Form to edit enry, getting "The date you submitted is not valid."

Tags: safecracker, saef

I am using Channel Form to edit an existing entry. I am wrapping the channel form inside a Channel Entries block so I can have more than one entry on a page (not using a segment variable to indicate the entry_id). Here is the code I am trying to get to work:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="image_bank" limit="1" disable="trackbacks|member_data|categories" rdf="off"} 

{exp:channel:form channel="image_bank" entry_id="{entry_id}" include_jquery="no"  include_assets="no" return="{site_url}/manage/index/" datepicker="no"}
<p>
Description: {field:image_description}<br>
Keywords: {field:image_keywords}<br>
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</p>

{/exp:channel:form}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

It actually does work in that it updates the entry. But it gives an error of “The date you submitted is not valid.” But it still updated the entry.

I have tried including hidden fields for the entry date and edit date but this did not help.  I have tried datepicker="no" and “yes”.

This seems like a basic function so I must be missing something basic. I am using ee 2.8.1.

Comment: For testing, if you take out the outer channel:entries tag pair and hardcode the entry_id parameter of the channel:form does it work without error? (I'm also assuming there aren't any custom date fields you have set to 'required'?)

Comment: Thanks Romans. I did have a custom date field. It was not required so I did not think that would be an issue. But deleting the field solves the problem. I will go back and include the field in a hidden field and see if I can get it to work.